# How to Load HTML from another file without going to another page (Single-Page App with Github Pages)?

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, github-pages

I'm trying to create a simple blog where at least the `<nav>` bar won't change, and so I would like to not have to load it on every single click.

To achieve this, I'm thinking about creating my posts in HTML files  without the `<head>`, the `<body>`, etc., only, say, the `<article>` tag and all the content inside it. Then, when the user clicks on a link, that content gets loaded onto the current page without the browser having to load a whole new page. But how exactly do I do this? How do I load/parse HTML from another file? — I'm new to creating single-page apps from scratch...

I know the `DOMParser` can parse strings into HTML, but first I would have to open the file itself and read it as a string. Is this the way to do it? — I don't want to have to copy-paste my articles as template literals onto the code itself, that makes writing the HTML content quite annoying and unmanageable.

> [This](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/fanaro.io) is the current Github Pages website if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: Use ajax to retrieve the html content

Comment: Could you be more specific? I would thank you for it. I wanted to try something with the [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object, do you mean something along those lines?

Comment: Yes, or the more modern `fetch()` API which is more robust than XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Nice, the `fetch` API really does seem to be what I need, and it is indeed more natural then `XMLHttpRequest`. I've created an [example](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/fanaro.io/blob/master/src/index.ts) of something that does work locally, but, when I push to Github, I get that requesting another page internally is giving me 404. Clicking anywhere on [this page](https://fanaroengineering.github.io/fanaro.io/) should make an `h1` tag appear, but all I get is 404 and `null`. Maybe this sort of stuff doesn't work on Github Pages?

Comment: Never mind, it is working. It's just that Github Pages took a while to update its database, so it took a while for it to appear. Do you want to write an answer with something like what I wrote or do you prefer that I do it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), but, as @charlietfl points out, the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is much more natural.

```
function appendArticle(): void {
  fetch("/articles/test.html")
    .then((response: Response) => response.text())
    .then((htmlAsString: string) => {
      const parser: DOMParser = new DOMParser();

      const articleDocument: Document = parser.parseFromString(htmlAsString, "text/html");

      const article: HTMLElement = articleDocument.querySelector("article")!;

      document.body.append(article);
    });
}

// You don't need to use `document.onclick`, this is just an example...
document.onclick = (_: MouseEvent) => appendArticle();
```

That does work even in the Github Pages context. The only issue you might encounter is *delay*: while Github isn't able to update its servers' databases the `fetch` operation will return `null` and you willl at most see `null` on the HTML screen.

Comment: The real problem though is when you make a request to a page different than the main domain (`/`). Since there's no server routing you accordingly, Github Pages will simply deliver the vanilla `<article>`. There's probably no solution to the problem, you will probably have to end up creating a server.